# how not to flood the html page with the innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have this code :

```
function addInDiv() {
    let div = document.getElementById("divName");
    div.innerHTML += '<p>' + "test" + '</p>'   
}
    
setInterval(addInDiv, 1000);
```

this code make

```
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
```

... infinitely and flood the computer CPU.

I would like "divName" to only contain the last 5 lines that have been added by `div.innerHTML`

so, how can i display the last 5 lines displayed so as not to flood the html page and the pc's cpu

thanks

Comment: Your code only adds the element once.

Comment: mistake, its not SetTimeout its SetInterval !

Answer (score 1):

Store the number of appended elements in a variable, increment it every time you append, and check whether its been appended 5 times or not. If it has, cancel the interval.

```js
var appended = 0;
var interval

function addInDiv() {
  if (++appended == 6) {
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
  let div = document.getElementById("divName");
  div.innerHTML += '<p>' + "test" + '</p>'
}

interval = setInterval(addInDiv, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="divName"></div>
```

Comment: indeed I made a mistake, I just corrected I will now read your code. Thank you

Comment: but this is not the solution sought because I would like the program to continue but that we go back up the first test and therefore add a new test instead of 5 (test was a test precisely when in reality it is not not all the time I add) like an autoscroll in fact

Comment: @PierreB You want, once 5 elements are there, for the latest element to replace the first one?

Comment: like div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight; without flooding the <p>test<p> browser

Comment: Please add *specific* details *in your question*.  Looks like you just want `$("p").first().remove()` so "only last 5 are displayed" - but maybe you just want a scrollbar with fixed height and `overflow:auto`.  Not sure how either of these reduce the CPU load.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
var counter = 0;
function addInDiv() {
    counter++
    if(counter <= 5) {
        $('#divName').append('<p>' + "test" + '</p>');
    }       
}
    
setInterval(addInDiv, 1000);
```